# Can Ant load a URL?

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build script which currently launches a server and then waits until a URL can be resolved before it carries out some Selenium tests for me. That task looks like this;

```
<target name="test.selenium" depends="compile.constants, launch.server" description="Run the Selenium tests">
    <echodesc/>
    <waitfor maxwait="1" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="2" checkeveryunit="second">
        <http url="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/"/>
    </waitfor>
    <exec executable="${deps.python}" spawn="false" failonerror="true" dir="src">
        <arg line="manage.py test --selenium-only" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

After that has been successful I want to call a URL which will shutdown the server but I'm unsure of how to do this with Ant. Is it possible to get Ant to call `127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/QUIT`?

I was previously achieving this with a `taskkill` command to the running process but this has started to cause Windows errors and that URL closes the server cleanly.

The best solution I can find is this macro to open a URL in the browser but this still causes me problems because I then have an open browser at the end of my tests; http://chris.m0nk3y.net/blog/post/opening-a-url-in-the-default-browser-with-ant

#### my solution

Ultimately I used the following ant target;

```
<target name="shutdown.server" depends="init.properties" description="Shutdown the server">
    <get src="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/QUIT" dest="NUL"/>
</target>
```

'NUL' enabled me to use get without dealing with a new file being created so this was perfect for the job \o/

Comment: That's it! The dest="NUL" was the hint I was searching for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get` task to call http url. Here is more info https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html.

For example `<get src="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/QUIT" dest="${temp.dir}/quit.res"/>`